# Using Host Selector in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I need help in setting the background-color of a page to a different color using Host Selector. I tried the example in stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hknw2a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss, not sure how to set for the whole page.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Non-standard elements are seen as `inline` by default as they aren't part of the HTML spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set **width** and **min-height** in Host selector to set background-color for the whole page.

```
body {
  margin:0px;
}

:host{
  background-color: aquamarine;
  display:block;// comment this tyo have "no background"
  width: 100vw;
  min-height:100px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, took time to make some changes in my code and fix. 
Finally worked with,
"width: 100%;
min-height:100vh;"